# Getting [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <b-modal> even though bootstrap-vue is registered

Tags: vuejs2, mocha.js, bootstrap-vue, vue-test-utils, mocha-webpack

A BootstrapVue b-modal component in a custom Vue component loads correctly in the browser. However, when testing using mocha+mochapack, it generates a Vue warning that the b-modal element is not registered. The test is using a localVue object that has BootstrapVue registered. All other bootstrap custom elements seem to be loading correctly, and do not generate any warnings.

I tried various things, including importing BModal from 'bootstrap-vue' and registering it as a component directly, but still got the same error.

```
import {mount, createLocalVue} from "@vue/test-utils"
import MyCustomModal from '../js/MyCustomModal';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
localVue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('MyCustomModal', () => {
    let wrapper = mount(MyCustomModal,{
            localVue
        });

    it('the content is "this is the content"', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(".modal-content").text()).toEqual('this is the content');
    });


});
```

The custom Vue component:

```
<template>
    <b-modal>
        <div class="modal-content">this is the content</div>
        <b-form>
           my form
        </b-form>
    </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return {};
        }
    }
</script>
```

The tests run correctly and pass, but it outputs the Vue warning for the b-modal element. It doesn't output the warning for b-form.

Comment: Do you try use `shallowMount` instead `mount` from vue-utlis?

Answer (score 2):

If only shallowMount not work. 
You can try stub your bootstrap's components individually.

Like this:

```
import {shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import { BModal, BForm } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import MyCustomModal from '../js/MyCustomModal';

describe('MyCustomModal', () => {
    let wrapper = shallowMount(MyCustomModal,{
            stubs: {
                "b-modal": BModal,
              "b-form": BForm
            }
        });

    it('the content is "this is the content"', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(".modal-content").text()).toEqual('this is the content');
    });

});
```

Comment: I tried stubbing the components this way, but I got an error: Error: [vue-test-utils]: options.stub values must be passed a string or component

Comment: Yeah, because that, I imported the components { BModal, BForm } individually from bootstrap-vue. Do you have imported components above?

Comment: If no working, maybe try stub with just string with component name like this: 

stubs: {
    "b-modal",
    "b-form"
}

Comment: Yeah, I imported the components BModal and BForm, didn't work. Stubbing them with strings allowed me to hide the error, which is good. However, now I can't test that the modal is actually working (meaning as a popup).

Comment: Yeah just string no have way to test the subcomponent just stub them. :/
But if you can import those components individually, certanly you will can test the components with stubs atributted.

Comment: stubs: { "b-modal", "b-form" }  <-- this is syntax error

Comment: Yeah, @CENT1PEDE you right. The right syntax must be ```stubs: { "b-modal": true, "b-form": true }``` or the explicit components instead true. Thanks for catch.

Doc stubs: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#stubs

Comment: `stubs: { "b-modal": true, "b-form": true }` works fine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `attachToDocument: true` flag when you mount `b-modal` (or your test component/app).  It needs reference to the document/body in order for it to open (needs to add classes, etc to `<body>` as well as a few listeners.

Comment: options.attachToDocument is deprecated in favor of options.attachTo

Comment: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#attachto

Answer (score 0):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils"
import MyCustomModal from '../js/MyCustomModal';
    
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

describe('MyCustomModal', () => {
    let wrapper = mount(MyCustomModal);

    it('the content is "this is the content"', () => {
        expect(wrapper.find(".modal-content").text()).toEqual('this is the content');
    });


});
```

Try that.